# Change the displayed select option with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got following problem:

I'm calling a bootstrap modal with a form in it. The form comes with a dropdown and looks like following:

```
<select id="requirement_id" name="requirement_id">
    <option value="2">Sample     Requirement</option>
    <option value="3">Second Req</option>
    <option value="5">New Req</option>
</select>
```

I added a piece of jquery with adds `selected="selected"`to a specific option, which i want to be selected by default.
When i submit the form, this option seems to be selected, but no matter which option gets selected by my script: The Text in the Select Field is always "Sample Requirement" (the first one)

Do you have an idea, how to change that?
My jQuery Code is following:

```
$('.add_feature').click(function(){
    $('#requirement_id option').each(function(){
      $(this).removeAttr('selected');
    });
    $('#requirement_id').find('option[value="'+$(this).data('requirement')+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overthinking it, you don't need to remove or add a `selected` attribute on the `option`. All you need to do is use `val()` on the `select` and let jQuery do the work for you.

```
$('#requirement_id').val(valueOfOptionToSelect));
```

In your case it seems to be:

```
$('#requirement_id').val($(this).data('requirement'));
```

Assuming `.add_feature` has a `data-requirement` containing the value of the option to select (2, 3, or 5)

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hGRvB/2/)

If you do want to do without `val()`, just change `attr()` to `prop()` in your code and the `removeAttr()` becomes unnecessary:

```
$('#requirement_id').find('option[value="' + $(this).data('requirement') + '"]').prop('selected', 'selected');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hGRvB/4/)

Comment: thank you, that worked for me. it pointed out that my solution was working, too but only if i tried to show someone my problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#requirement_id').val($(this).data('requirement'));
```